# How to display Cover Image of an epub file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, epub, flutter-plugin

The [dart-epub](https://pub.dev/packages/epub) plugin mentions an example on how to get Cover Image:

```
// Book's cover image (null if there is no cover)
Image coverImage = epubBook.CoverImage;
```

How can I display this? I keep getting an error

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider<Object>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: I figured it out

Import the image and epub package as

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as image;
import 'package:epub/epub.dart' as epub;
```

Open the epub file

```
      // Change the location to wherever your epub file is located
      var targetFile = new File('location/epubFile.epub');
      List<int> bytes = await targetFile.readAsBytes();
      epub.EpubBook epubBook = await epub.EpubReader.readBook(bytes);
```

Save the Cover Image to some location (ideally same folder as the epub file so it easier to delete together)

```
// Save the Cover Image to some location
if (await File('location/epubFileCoverImage.png').exists()) {
        print("File exists");
      } else {
        try {
          File('location/epubFileCoverImage.png')
              .writeAsBytesSync(image.encodePng(epubBook.CoverImage));
        } catch (e) {
          print("Error Saving Cover Image");
          print(e);
          coverError = true;
        }
      }
```

Use Exception handling as there may be errors loading the Cover Image for some epub files
Finally to display it in the Widget tree:

```
coverError ? Image.asset("assets/Error.png")
           : Image.file(File('location/epubFileCoverImage.png')),
```

Comment: What happened if the image will be in jpeg or gif format?